# PDO::FETCH_CLASS without passing class name as a parameter

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

i came across a piece of code where `PDO::FETCH_CLASS` is being called without passing the name of the class as a parameter, like this:

```
  function getUsers() {
    $DBH = $this->getDbh();
    $query = "SELECT * FROM users";

    try {
      $STH = $DBH->query($query);
      $users = $STH->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS);
    } catch(PDOException $e) {

    }

    return $users;
  }
```

now, in the official [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php)  it says:

> If fetch_style includes PDO::FETCH_CLASSTYPE (e.g. PDO::FETCH_CLASS | PDO::FETCH_CLASSTYPE) then the name of the class is determined from a value of the first column.

so im not sure i understood exactly what they mean nor how it works.
let's say i have `users` table with one record

- id:1
- name:Josh
- so on..

so how can `PDO::FETCH_CLASS` know what's the class name? can i add column to my record with the class name in a way `FETCH_CLASS` will get the class name from the database? example of record structure will be highly appreciated ...thx

*I am  testing this class but not the author so changing the class is irrelevant

Comment: I have this weird feeling that this is a typo, and they meant 'table name' - but I am basing this on zero factual evidence :)

Comment: Actually, it just returns a `\stdClass` instance, like `PDO::FETCH_OBJ`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For *fetchAll* method, if classname is not supplied and `PDO::FETCH_CLASSTYPE` flag is not raised, a `stdClass` object is returned (just like with `PDO::FETCH_OBJ`). This is what happens ([lxr](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_5/ext/pdo/pdo_stmt.c#1436)):

```
1436    switch(how & ~PDO_FETCH_FLAGS) {
1437    case PDO_FETCH_CLASS:
1438        switch(ZEND_NUM_ARGS()) {
1439        case 0:
1440        case 1:
1441            stmt->fetch.cls.ce = zend_standard_class_def;
1442            break
```

Then, in `do_fetch`, as there's no class name supplied, this value remains as is. That makes sense, as `stdClass` is sometimes considered an anonymous class of a sort. )

---

That explains the code you have to deal with; @eggyal's answer explains how one can use `PDO::FETCH_CLASS || PDO::FETCH_CLASSTYPE` combo. It's actually a pretty powerful technique, allowing you to skip the boilerplate switch in factory methods.

Comment: The indisputable proof of an answer that references the source code... love that :)

Answer (score 2):

1. > im not sure i understood exactly what they mean nor how it works

   What they mean is that instead of

   ```php
   $STH = $DBH->query("SELECT * FROM users");
   $users = $STH->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'UserClass');
   ```

   you *can* do the following:

   ```php
   $STH = $DBH->query("SELECT 'UserClass', users.* FROM users");
   $users = $STH->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS | PDO::FETCH_CLASSTYPE);
   ```

   However, this is not especially useful: why hardcode the class name into the SQL only to have MySQL return it with every record and PDO parse each of those fields (i.e. for each record) when instantiating the resultant objects?  Better just to specify the class name as the second argument to `fetchAll()`, as shown in the first example above.
2. > should i add column to my record with the class name?

   Well, indeed, one could do that too—and that is a far more useful use of this functionality: it enables the class of each resultant object to depend upon the record itself, which may be useful in some cases (i.e. where not all records in a resultset are of the same "type"—for example: perhaps some records should instantiate `Employee` objects, whilst others should instantiate `Customer` objects).

Comment: That isn't my downvote, but this `SELECT 'UserClass'` should *probably* be ticks `\`` or none at all. Probably why they downvoted and kept their mouth shut.

Comment: `'SELECT 'UserClass', users.* FROM users'` isn't valid PHP and will produce a fatal error.

Comment: And you're correct in describing the possible use-cases for FETCH_CLASS || FETCH_CLASSTYPE `fetch` combo, hence +1 from me. )

Comment: @eggyal comment #1 from me still applies. Matter 'o fact, I even upvoted ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii-: I changed the PHP string from single-quoted to double-quoted—so `'UserClass'` is now a SQL string literal, as it should be (rather than some erroneous PHP identifier, as it was).

Comment: @eggyal that part I don't know about, in regards to UserClass.

Comment: @Fred-ii-:  It's just a plain old string, being the name of whatever class the user wishes to instantiate.